# Problemas para ajustar a regressão linear em Stan

Tags: r, modelagem, regressão

Estou tendo problemas para ajustar um modelo de regressão linear no stan. Ao observar a mensagem de erro, nota-se a identificação na parte do bloco dos parâmetros transformados.

Veja abaixo a estrutura do código em stan.

```
Packages:

library(rstan)
library(bayesplot)
```

Dados:

```
head(Orange)
cols <- c(colnames(Orange[-1]))
Orange <- Orange[,cols]
str(Orange)
```

Código em stan:

Vejam que a estrutura de blocos dentro do stan segue o padrão recomendado, porém não consigo identificar qual parte do código pode me parecer errada.

```
y = Orange$circumference
x = Orange$age
n = length(y)

regresstan = '
data{
  int n;
  real y[n];
  real x[n];
}

parameters{
  real alpha;
  real beta;
  real sigma;
}

transformed parameters{
    real mu[n];
    mu = alpha + beta*x;
}

model{
  //Priors
  alpha ~ normal(0, 100);
  beta ~ normal(0, 100);
  sigma ~ uniform(0, 100);

  //Likelihood
    y ~ normal(mu, sigma);
}
'
```

Erro:

```
SYNTAX ERROR, MESSAGE(S) FROM PARSER:
No matches for: 

  real * real[ ]

Available argument signatures for operator*:

  real * real
  vector * real
  row_vector * real
  matrix * real
  row_vector * vector
  vector * row_vector
  matrix * vector
  row_vector * matrix
  matrix * matrix
  real * vector
  real * row_vector
  real * matrix

No matches for: 

  real + ill-formed

Available argument signatures for operator+:

  int + int
  real + real
  vector + vector
  row_vector + row_vector
  matrix + matrix
  vector + real
  row_vector + real
  matrix + real
  real + vector
  real + row_vector
  real + matrix
  +int
  +real
  +vector
  +row_vector
  +matrix

Expression is ill formed.
 error in 'modele28054257a16_a9d23411185fa271b60f20be43062e80' at line 16, column 23
  -------------------------------------------------
    14: transformed parameters{
    15:     real mu[n];
    16:     mu = alpha + beta*x;
                              ^
    17: }
  -------------------------------------------------

Error in stanc(file = file, model_code = model_code, model_name = model_name,  : 
  failed to parse Stan model 'a9d23411185fa271b60f20be43062e80' due to the above error.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi do seu modelo, você esta definindo uma classe `real` enquanto deveria estar usando `vector` para os objetos `x`, `y` e `mu`:

```
data{
  int n;
  vector[n] y;
  vector[n] x;
}

parameters{
  real alpha;
  real beta;
  real sigma;
}

transformed parameters{
    vector[n] mu;
    mu = alpha + beta * x;
}

model{
  //Priors
  alpha ~ normal(0, 100);
  beta ~ normal(0, 100);
  sigma ~ uniform(0, 100);

  //Likelihood
    y ~ normal(mu, sigma);
}
```

É sempre importante testar seu modelo com dados falsos, nos quais você já conhece os valores dos parâmetros.

Tente também definir os limites [lógicos] dos parâmetros para reduzir as transições divergentes e acelerar a aproximação:

```
real<lower = 0, upper = 2> alpha;
```

**EDIT**

Você pode manter a mesma estrutura do model apresentado na pergunta e adicionar um loop for no bloco `transformed_parameters`:

```
data{
int n;
real y[n];
real x[n];
}

parameters{
real alpha;
real beta;
real sigma;
}

transformed parameters{
    real mu[n];
        for(i in 1:n){
        mu[i] = alpha + beta*x[i];
    }
}

model{
//Priors
alpha ~ normal(0, 100);
beta ~ normal(0, 100);
sigma ~ uniform(0, 100);

//Likelihood
    y ~ normal(mu, sigma);
}
```

Comment: Se teu `n` é igual à 35 acho que é normal que ele estime 35 `mu`s, não? Editei a responsta com uma outra possibilidade de calcular o `mu` com um vector.

Comment: Então porque tu defines `real mu[n];` desta maneira no teu modelo inicial? A maneira como você define `mu` é pra que ele seja estimado `n` vezes.

Comment: Da uma olhada neste exemplo, talvez possa te ajudar: https://github.com/stan-dev/example-models/blob/master/ARM/Ch.23/electric.stan